# Align div at bottom of flex

Tags: html, css

I have this card:

```css
.do_card {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: 0.3s;
  width: 220px;
  height: 320px;
}

.do_container {
  padding: 2px 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="do_card">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" style="width:220px;height:150px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;display:block;">
  <div class="do_container">
    <p style="text-align: center;">Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between;">
      <p><a href="https://www.test.com" style="color:black"><i class="test"></i> GET IT</a>
        <p>Like</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I get the "GET IT" and "Like" to always be at the bottom of the card?

Setting the `do_card` to `position: relative;` and the div with "Get it" and "Like"
to `position: absoulute; bottom:0px;` does not work

Comment: How about setting it from: ```position:absoult; margin-bottom:0px;``` to ```position:absolute; bottom:0;```? And also apply the relative positioning the parent.

Comment: ah sorry @prettyInPink, typo on my end. `position:absolute; bottom:0;` does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make sure the content set to `absolute` remains within the desired element (card in your case), make sure to set its parent to `position: relative;` (.do_card in your case)

It does seem to work for me as mentioned in the comment:

```html
<style>
.do_card {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  transition: 0.3s;
  width: 220px;
  height: 320px;
  position: relative;
}

.do_container {
  padding: 2px 16px;
}
</style>


<div class="do_card">
   <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" style="width:220px;height:150px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;display:block;">
  <div class="do_container">
    <p style="text-align: center;">Lorem Ipsum</p> 
    <div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between; position: absolute; bottom: 0; width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0 16px; left: 0;">
        <p><a href="https://www.test.com" style="color:black"><i class="test"></i> GET IT</a>
        <p>Like</p>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Give some explanation please, for example you've add position relative to the card, and it's why position absolute works here

Comment: @Sfili_81, he did know about that as mentioned in his question; ```do-card``` to ```position: relative;```

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer a "non-absolute" solution whenever possible. In fact, you're able to achieve the layout with flexbox. Here's how:

First, you need to put your content inside the card into 2 blocks (top and bottom).

Then, you can use `flex-direction: column;` and `justify-content: space-between;` on the card.

```css
.do_card {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: 0.3s;
  width: 220px;
  height: 320px;
  /* vertical stretched alignment */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.do_card img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.do_container {
  padding: 2px 16px;
}

.do_container_bottom {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="do_card">
  <!-- top -->
  <div class="do_container">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" style="width:220px;height:150px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;display:block;">
    <p style="text-align: center;">Lorem Ipsum</p>
  </div>

  <!-- bottom -->
  <div class="do_container_bottom">
    <a href="https://www.test.com" style="color:black"><i class="test"></i> GET IT</a>
    <p>Like</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: should also add `align-items: center;` on div containing "GET IT" / "Like"

Comment: @カメロン you're right, though that's not the OP's main problem, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

if you want button "GET IT" and "Like" to always be at the bottom of the card, you can set do_container to flex_grow: 1 to make it take as much space as possible and set the element inside with justify-content: space-between

```css
.do_card {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: 0.3s;
  width: 220px;
  height: 320px;
  /* add flex */
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

img {
  width:220px;
  height:150px;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  display:block;
}

.do_container {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  /* add flex-grow to make it fill the height of the container */
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  /* make it space-between to set get_it and like button on bottom of card */
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.title {
  text-align: center;
}

.action_container {
  display: flex; 
  justify-content: space-between;
}

p {
  color:black
}
```

```html
<div class="do_card">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300">
  <div class="do_container">
    <p class="title">Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <div class="action_container">
      <p><a href="https://www.test.com"><i class="test"></i> GET IT</a>
      <p>Like</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```